# HTTP GET limit when communicate between 2 windows applications

Tags: windows, http, get, port

I have program listening on port 10000. Program accept HTTP GET requests. Other programs in same computer will send requests. Because there is no communication outside computer - Ist it correct to accept that url size limit will not be applied?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your programs are both server and client, so no other components are involved!? So the only limitations are set by **your** programs. Or are you using some third part library? Then you'll have to check the documentation on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just finished testing. Communication between 2 programs using port is not depending on any URL size limits. It only depends on programs.